# Matrix Lie Algebra isomorphic to a vector field Lie algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ .

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\ell$ be the vector field Lie algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ generated by the set $\{X,Y,Z\}$ where, 
$$X=y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\ Y=z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \quad \mbox{and} \quad Z=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

I need to find a matrix Lie algebra which is isomorphic to $\ell$. I don't think any of the classical examples is useful in this case, any idea or any hint thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why isn't any of the classical examples useful? All Lie algebra structures on $\Bbb R^3$ are classified.

Comment: Yes you're right, I hurried to say that. How are the Lie algebras on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ classified?

Comment: See for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165656/how-many-three-dimensional-real-lie-algebras-are-there).